# Can't get Android Emulator to work in Linux

Tags: android-emulator

I have Fedora 10, it's an old machine.

When I launch the Emulator, it comes up, but I don't
get any initial "Android" display text on the screen, and I've tried
waiting ages.

I installed the Java JDK 7 first then 'android-sdk-r22.2.1-linux.tgz'
and I even set the "alternates" for Java.

I've tried several Emulators, like the 4.3 with the armeabi
and an earlier 3.2.  I also tried launching them from the command line with:

emulator -no-audio -gpu off -avd [AVDName]   and I even tried '-force-32bit'
but nothing is working.

I've used the Emulator on Windows for a long time, so I'm
very familiar with how to use them, but I just can't get them working on Linux,
what can I try?

Thanks!

Comment: Try the command line option to display the console, or see if you can connect to it via adb.

Comment: If Fedora 10 supports KVM, switch to the x86 emulator image: http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#accel-vm

Comment: Usually you can't connect to it until it's gone through

Comment: I turned on '-verbose' and the output stops at this point, I tried turning on DDMS and doing a 'start-server, and turned the firewall off:    emulator: Could not open file: (null)/system/build.prop: No such file or directory
emulator: control console listening on port 5556, ADB on port 5557
emulator: can't connect to ADB server: Connection refused
emulator: ping program: /usr/local/bin/android-sdk-linux/tools/ddms
emulator: ping command: /usr/local/bin/android-sdk-linux/tools/ddms ping emulator 22.2.1.0 "" "" ""

Answer (score 2):

This will work:

1) Create a Phone in Eclipse using the Android Virtual Device Manager
   (Navigation Bar | Window | Android Virtual Device Manager)

2) Open a terminal in: yourInstallationFolder/sdk/tools

3) Type: ./emulator @theNameofYourPhone -force-32bit

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same issue, with the latest build tools - emulator would not launch, adding `-debug-init` showed that it couldn't get past this line:

> ping command: /path/to/android-sdk-linux_86/tools/ddms ping
>   emulator 22.3.0 "NVIDIA Corporation" "GeForce 8600 GTS/PCIe/SSE2"
>   "3.3.0 NVIDIA 331.20

But *sometimes* it worked, it got past this and printed some debug info about `display surface, pixel format` etc - then emulator was working.

I tried soooo many things, none worked, but it seems I found **the solution**!

It looks like emulator *always* starts OK if I launch it from the *first* virtual desktop! And not working, 'hanging' - when launched from others.

Took some time to figure out, because my main 'development' virtual desktop is a second one :)

Dunno whos bug this is, NVIDIA's, xorg's or emulator's, but I hope this workaround will keep working :)

Comment: Same issue here, though I havent been able to solve the issue. Regardless of which desktop I launch the emulator from, its just stuck at "ping emulator 22.3.0 "NVIDIA Corporation" "Quadro K2000/PCIe/SSE2" "4.4.0 NVIDIA 331.20"

Comment: @Zygote yes, unfortunately later I discovered that desktop was not exactly the thing that caused this bug. The only thing that helped is logging out, restarting 'gdm' and logging back in. Sometimes several restarts were needed. But later somehow this bug went away by itself, I'm not sure why. Maybe some package updates fixed this. I'm on Arch Linux, so I update more or less often... Good luck to you! :)

Comment: Yeah, Im on Arch as well. Restarting gdm doesnt fix it for me though.

Comment: Starting to sound like some distro-specific problem than. I also use nvidia driver, maybe that's related. Let's hope it will go away for you just like it did for me. Maybe some package updates are needed for you to do... :)

Answer (score 0):

I have been pulling my hair out on this issue all week... I finally just tried a different DE. I launched an icewm session and the emulator is not running just fine. It seems to be an issue either with GTK or KDE's WM.

Any ways, I hope this helps solve the issues you might be having.