# Android Emulator stuck at ddms ping command in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: android, android-emulator

I am trying to run Android emulator on Ubuntu 14.04 x64.
On Starting emulator, it just displays black screen.

On running the emulator from the command line (`./emulator -avd avdname -verbose`) with verbose option I found that emulator freezes at the **ping** command as shown below in the console output:

**Console output:**

```
emulator: Kernel parameters: qemu.gles=0 qemu=1 console=ttyS0 android.qemud=ttyS1 android.checkjni=1 ndns=1
emulator: autoconfig: -scale 0.445312
emulator: emulator window was out of view and was recentered
emulator: control console listening on port 5554, ADB on port 5555
emulator: can't connect to ADB server: Connection refused
emulator: ping program: /home/user_name/Documents/android_studio/android-studio/sdk/tools/ddms
emulator: ping command: /home/user_name/Documents/android_studio/android-studio/sdk/tools/ddms ping emulator 22.6.4.0 "Intel Open Source Technology Center" "Mesa DRI Intel(R) Ironlake Mobile " "2.1 Mesa 10.1.3"
```

*

I have searched through many solutions, one also mentioned on SO ([Android Emulator Freezing On Startup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8066123/android-emulator-freezing-on-startup) and [Can't get Android Emulator to work in Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19549923/cant-get-android-emulator-to-work-in-linux)) but none seem to solve the problem.

Emulator was working earlier and though I am not sure I suspect that when I updated Ubuntu to 14.04, this problem might have started then.

Would be grateful for any help/advice.